# Parent to sub-domain AJAX POST requests with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'll start by saying i have spent the last 3 days looking for an answer to this and have yet to find a solution that works! :(

I would like to be able to POST from `www.example.com` to `api.example.com` preferably using JQuery.

I have managed to get GET requests to work using `document.domain` and `<base href="example.com"/>`

This is all secured using SSL.

I have read about using an iFrame to load a page on the subdomain and post the forms from the parent domain using javascript but i don't really want to pursue this route (if possible).

Also if cross-domain POSTing isn't viable, when using https are there any security benefits with using POST as compared to GET?

Thanks,

Jamie

Comment: GET request **and their parameters** can be logged in your web server's log, and by proxies, be aware of that security point.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the document domain in the main domain and the subdomain, you should be able to make Ajax calls between the two.

**Parent Page**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.domain = "example.com";
</script>
<iframe src="setDocumentDomain.html" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

**iframe setDocumentDomain.html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.domain = "example.com";
        </script>
        <title>Set Domain</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```